# Explain why the Fourier series of $|\cos(2t)|$ cannot be $\cos(2t)$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

> Question: Explain why the Fourier series of $|\cos(2t)|$ cannot be $\cos(2t)$.

I know that $|\cos(2t)|$ is even, so its Fourier series does not have sine term.
However, I am not sure why its Fourier series of $|\cos(2t)|$ cannot be $\cos(2t)$.

Comment: A fourier series is a sum of sines and cosines, you don't have either, as $|\cos(x)| \neq \cos x,\sin x$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor There was a typo in my question. I edited it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut There was a typo in my question. I edited it.

Comment: @Idonknow because $|\cos2t|\neq\cos2t$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @Nosrati Not in the usual sense of "almost everywhere".

Comment: @Nosrati: half everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a weird question !

Because $|\cos\pi|\ne\cos\pi$.

For completeness, one should add that $|\cos\pi|$ is continuous at $\pi$ so that if it has a Fourier series, it must converge to $|\cos\pi|$.

Comment: I suspect that the expected answer is different, but the question is not explicit enough.

Comment: I can see a reason to ask this: often on MSE I see questions about Fourier series that ask for the expansion of $f$ on $[a,b]$, where $f$ is not even assumed to be periodic. The usual way to deal with this (possibly implicitly) is to make up a periodic function $g$ that agrees with $f$ on $[a,b]$ and to get its Fourier coefficients (it's even possible to choose cosine or sine coefficients if one can find an even or an odd function $g$). In that sense, $\cos(2t)$ would be a valid Fourier series for $|\cos(2t)|$ on, say, $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: also thinkable that the OP confuses $|\cos x|$ and $\cos|x|$.